# Are there lines of reasoning that can only be introduced into a case via an expert witness?

Tags: united-states, civil-procedure, criminal-procedure, witnesses, rules-of-evidence

Say some technical question is important to a court case.

One side brings in an expert witness on the subject to testify that the answer is in fact A in their expert opinion.

Is the other side allowed to go through the technical details of the subject in an attempt to show the reasoning behind, and talk the judge and jury through, why they think the answer is really B? By essentially getting up and reading off a page of math, or a bunch of textbook definitions of technical concepts and then an argument in terms of them?

"Well, you see, the speed of my client is constrained by Newton's laws of motion, and particularly the equation so-and-so, and if we take the first derivative of that we of course get such and such, ... And by this analysis, we conclude that there is no more than a 2.3% probability my client could have been speeding, given the basic principles of microwave physics in the textbook introduced as Exhibit Q, and the accuracy rating printed on the measurement equipment in Exhibit J."

Or is there a low limit on the technical complexity of arguments that may be made, and any argument of significant technical complexity is forbidden except via the mediating professional opinion of a qualified expert witness?

Answer (score 7):

You'll generally need an expert witness to testify to anything that requires "scientific, technical, or other specialized knowledge" beyond the knowledge of the average person.

So although a defendant likely could not present the argument you're describing on his own, he could introduce it through his an expert witness, or as part of a cross-examination of the other side's witness.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes; opinions

Experts are the only type of witness that is allowed to testify as to their opinion; all other witnesses may only testify as to the facts (what they directly experienced).

For [example](https://youtu.be/W7YoxrKa4f0), while the lay witnesses can testify that they saw a '64 Buick Tempest, an expert can state their opinion that only a 1963 Pontiac Tempest could have made the tyre tracks.

It is extremely common for expert witnesses to be briefed by each side and arrive at different opinions - reasonable minds *can* differ. However, even though each side pays for their own experts, they work *for* the court - an expert witness is an officer of the court (just like the lawyers), and their loyalty is to justice, not to the side paying them. They are also strictly prohibited from crossing the line into advocacy - that's what the lawyers are there for. Experts do sometimes need to be reminded of their obligations.

As an arbitrator, I'm a big fan of expert conclave or "hot-tubbing", where you lock the experts in a room without the lawyers, food, or water until they agree. Well, not quite. You can't lock them in, and you have to give them food and water, but you do keep the lawyers away. They then issue a joint report stating the areas where they agree and the areas where they disagree and why, and then you only have to rule on the disagreements.